# How to add static fields to a class via decorator?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-decorators

I have a problem with sqlalchemy and legacy database. Suppose I have a models like that

```
class A(Base):
    foo = Column(String)
    modified_at = Column(DateTime, default=func.now, onupdate=func.now())

class B(Base):
    bar = Column(String)
    modified_at = Column('SOME_NAME', DateTime, default=func.now, onupdate=func.now())
```

As you can see there is a code duplication here in modified_at field. Both classes have modified_at field to track time of last modification, but with different column names.

This could be solved using metaclasses, but it would actually require basically the same amount of code to pass column name as it is with solution with code duplication (especially in python2 as in python2 you can't pass arguments to metaclass easily)

So what I thought of is to use decorate class

```
def modified_at(col_name=None):
    def decorator(cls):
        cls.modified_at = Column(col_name, Datetime) # etc
        return cls
return decorator

@modified_at('SOME_NAME')
class B(Base):
    bar = Column(String)
```

But this gives me error when instantiating B(bar='some value')

```
TypeError decorator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bar'
```

Comment: Usually you would use a common base class or a mix-in class to inherit from.

Comment: @KlausD. Yeah, that's what I was doing untill I found that the **column name is different** in classes.

Comment: Then you write a new line. Readability count.

Comment: @KlausD. Where do you think I need to add a new line?

Comment: If the declarion differs, you add a new nomal declaration line for the field. It is initialization code which is run once and having a clear readable model is more important than DRY.

Comment: @KlausD. I disagree, because in this case it's just technical information for debugging purposes, that just hinders the real business model. The decorator is perfectly readable imho even if it would be just common business logic either, but in this case it add readability, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a mixin. From the SQLAlchemy docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#mixing-in-columns

```
class TimestampMixin(object):
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())

class MyModel(TimestampMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    id =  Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(1000))
```

Instead, define a function that returns your mixin:

```
def custom_mixin(param):
    class MyMixin(object):
        created_at = Column(DateTime, param, default=func.now())
    return MyMixin

class MyModel(custom_mixin('foobar'), Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    id =  Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(1000))
```

You could also just define a function to return your configured Column() object, and configure the class normally.